# how do I disable a log message that exists in the Django source?

Tags: django

e.g. in get_response() at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L133

there is a

```
 logger.warning('Not Found: %s', request.path,
                extra={
                    'status_code': 404,
                    'request': request
                })
```

...which seems to log something every time a request 404's I think.

This is clogging up my logs as (for instance) RSS bots crawl some old, non-working URLs on my site

I'd like to stop the logging noise,  so I've tried something like the below in my LOGGING config in settings.py.

```
LOGGING = {
    ...

    'loggers': { 
       ...
       'django.core.handlers': {
        'handlers': ['app_logs'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'ERROR'
    },
}
```

Here, I'm trying to quiet the logger.warning by setting the module log level of django.core.handlers to ERROR, but it seems to be not working.  Anyone know what to check or do?

Maybe I'm missing something obvious or perhaps flat out doing it wrong hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [correct logger name](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L18) is `django.request`.

Comment: thanks for the link to the line I should have been looking at!